# Optimization of simple method

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine

In given below method, there is a lot casting and as far as I know it is quite coslty for CLR. I would like to optimize it, however I cannot change this method signature.

```
public uint GetValueBetween (uint beginColor, uint endColor , float percent)
{
    int difference = (int)endColor - (int)beginColor; // can be signed negative integer

    float fValue = UnityEngine.Mathf.Abs((float)difference) * percent; // percent must be given in range 0.0 - 1.0, that is why I am not dividing it by 100;

    if (difference < 0)
    {
        return beginColor - (uint)UnityEngine.Mathf.RoundToInt (fValue);
    }

    return (uint)UnityEngine.Mathf.RoundToInt (fValue);
}
```

I have few ideas on how to remove casting, like not casting in the first line of body of this method to `Int32` from `uint` 3 times, but just check what number is bigger and adopt all the rest of the code to it.

Anyway I would like to ask you about it, what are your ideas.

Comment: Have you profiled this to make certain it is as costly as you think it is?  Also, where are endColor and beginColor coming from?

Comment: You don't use `end` or `begin` in the method.   Should they actually be named `beginColor` and `endColor`?

Comment: You certainly don't require those int casts in your opening line. `difference` should be a float. And you can then remove all those casts, including the float one from your second line. I'd also just get the value of UnityEngine.Mathf.RoundToInt(fValue) as a uint ONCE and then refer to it in your returns.

Comment: @DavidL no I didnt profile it, but I just was reading lately about casting numeric types, and was taking in account it is called many times in the frame. And sorry for mistake, end and begin should be endColor and beginColor, will edit it now.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi this is true completly, but still casting in few places can be omited.

Comment: @ManoDestra can you make answer with your comment?

Comment: And here is the quote from where I took this idea of costly numeric casting: **Numeric type conversions are usually expensive, take them out of the loops and recursive functions and use the same numeric types when possible.** http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8052/Type-casting-impact-over-execution-performance-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting between types of the same size (e.g. uint and int) is usually zero-cost, because it just changes from unsigned to signed cpu instructions.

Casting from int to float is likely to be very expensive though, first because it requires a non-trivial format conversion (all floating point values are normalized to one digit, so compute N for 1.xxxxx * 2^N), and also because floating point registers are vectors in modern CPUs, so you are loading a single value into a register that can hold between 8 and 32 of those values.

Since you aren't actually using the floating point value at all, and since you are applying Abs to the signed value, you can eliminate most of the cost very easily just by scaling the floating point percent to an appropriate integer value (I use 100 here, but you can choose a larger value, just remember to divide by the integer equivalent at the end of each statement, and you might test whether it is faster to multiply by powers of two rather than powers of ten, just in case the floating point unit bothers to optimize for that).

```
public uint GetValueBetween (uint beginColor, uint endColor , float percent)
{
    if(endColor < beginColor)
    {
        uint difference = beginColor - endColor;
        return beginColor - ((uint)(percent * 100.0) * difference) / 100;
    }
    else
    {
        uint difference = endColor - beginColor;
        return ((uint)(percent * 100.0) * difference) / 100;
    }
}
```

I split out difference as a separate variable to illustrate the key difference in the conditions, but you can inline that instead if you prefer.

Comment: It is night here now, so I will test it tommorow, but for know your answer looks the best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per your request for an answer, I'd do the following...

```
public uint GetValueBetween(uint beginColor, uint endColor , float percent)
{
    float difference = endColor - beginColor; // can be signed negative integer

    // percent must be given in range 0.0 - 1.0, that is why I am not dividing it by 100;
    float fValue = UnityEngine.Mathf.Abs(difference) * percent;
    var rounded = (uint)UnityEngine.Mathf.RoundToInt(fValue);
    if (difference < 0)
    {
        rounded = beginColor - rounded;
    }

    return rounded;
}
```

Isn't necessarily THAT much more "efficient", but it's a little cleaner at least.

Comment: Thanks, but still in first line there is implicit cast from uint to float. But tue I can remove with that second cast.

Comment: Yes, it is implicit, but you can't get round that. There's no real need to do it explicitly given that there's no loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not convinced that this method would be a performance bottleneck, at the very least the method can be simplified considerably to remove the branch:

```
public uint GetValueBetween(uint beginColor, uint endColor, float percent)
{
    return (uint) UnityEngine.Mathf.RoundToInt( ( 1 - percent ) * beginColor + percent * endColor );
}
```

Comment: This is elegant, I need to test it. Thanks for effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your method do quite a similar thing to Unity's [LerpUnclamped](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpUnclamped.html). And this is the code of it.

```
public static float LerpUnclamped (float a, float b, float t)
{
    return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

As it is from Unity, I think it's good to copy. So your method can be rewritten like this.

```
public uint GetValueBetween (uint beginColor, uint endColor , float percent)
{
    return beginColor + (uint)((endColor-beginColor)*percent);
}
```